# Can't write to BLE device's characteristic anymore after reconnect

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, zebra-printers

I'm writing printing data to the `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` of a Zebra ZD410 printer. I do this by chunking the data into 20 byte chunks and writing a chunk at a time with the following code:

```
mCharacteristic.setValue(bytes);
boolean status = mGatt.writeCharacteristic(mCharacteristic);
```

and then waiting until I receive `BluetoothGattCallback.onCharacteristicWrite()` before initiating the writing of the next chunk. This works fine.

If I `disconnect()` and `close()` the `BluetoothGatt` and later connect to the same device again with `BluetoothDevice.connectGatt()` and then try to write to the `Characteristic` after `onServicesDiscovered()` has been called is done and I have my `Characteristic` again, writing will fail. What I mean by this is that when I write to the `Characteristic` now, `onCharacteristicWrite()` will be called with a `Characteristic` who's `getValue()` returns the value of the last write on the old Gatt.

After trying to solve this for two days and reading tons of SO posts I haven't found a solution.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**
Here is the code for the `BluetoothGattCallback`

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState)
    {
        FALog.i(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange Status: " + status);
        switch (newState)
        {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                FALog.i(TAG, "gattCallback STATE_CONNECTED");
                gatt.discoverServices();
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                disconnectAndCloseGatt();
                mCharacteristic = null;
                connectionFailed();
                FALog.e(TAG, "gattCallback STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            default:
                FALog.e(TAG, "gattCallback STATE_OTHER");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)
    {
        BluetoothGattService service = gatt.getService(PRINTER_SERVICE_UUID);
        if (service != null)
        {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic
                    (PRINTER_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
            if (characteristic != null)
            {
                mCharacteristic = characteristic;
                mInternalState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                mState = State.CONNECTED;
                notifyStateChanged();
                print("~JA");
                FALog.d(TAG, "Printer connected");
                mBluetoothActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        mListener.onPrinterConnected();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)
    {
        FALog.d(TAG, "received onCharacteristicWrite " + new String(characteristic.getValue()) + "; success: " +
                (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS));
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
        {
            handler.removeCallbacks(writeRunnable);
            popQueueAndReleaseLock();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of your BluetoothGattCallback? If you are indeed discovering the services again, then it shouldn't fail. I'm not sure what else it might be without seeing more code, maybe it's a bug on the peripheral side.

Comment: @RobertoBetancourt added it in

Comment: What is the `status` you receive in your `onCharacteristicWrite`-method?

Comment: @Christopher the status is  BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS

Comment: Your GattCallback seems fine. Does this characteristic has write permissions? Perhaps you should attempt to read the characteristic after the write to confirm that the value was written correctly.

Comment: @RobertoBetancourt the characteristic has no permissions (`getPermissions` returns `0`) and `getProperty` returns `8`, which is `PROPERTY_WRITE`. If I try to read the characteristic, `onCharacteristicRead` doesn't get called

Comment: @HePa oh that's weird. Perhaps the lack of read properties in the characteristic is the reason why your peripheral is not returning the new value with getValue(). It appears that the issue is totally related to your peripheral and not something on the Android side. Better check the manufacturer's documentation.

Comment: @RobertoBetancourt that's my feeling now, too. Thank you for your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Try `writeCharacteristic` after the `onDescriptorWrite()` callback instead of `onServicesDiscovered()` callback. `writeDescriptor` holds the mDeviceBusy.